# Catch Symfony 2 exceptions during the boot sequence

Tags: php, symfony, exception, events, kernel

I read about kernel events in Symfony documentation : http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel.html

It's written : `As you've seen, you can create and attach event listeners to any of the events dispatched during the HttpKernel::handle() cycle`

No problem to do that, I can create a custom exception listener and listen the kernel events.

But how can I catch potential errors during the boot sequence (because no listeners are called):

```
public function handle(Request $request, $type = HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST, $catch = true)
{
    if (false === $this->booted) {
        $this->boot(); // Error can be thrown
    }

    return $this->getHttpKernel()->handle($request, $type, $catch);
}
```

I can have this kind of errors, if I provide a wrong access to database (`DriverException`) for example.

In dev mode, it's ok because I have a default error handler with `DebugBundle` but in production it's a white screen.

How can I handle that properly ?

Comment: You can put a try/catch block around the code in web/app.php.  Not entirely sure what you can do with any caught exceptions but at least you can catch them

Answer (score 1):

No need to catch errors at the booting stage within the application itself.

In general application can not intercept all possible errors. For example, out of memory. Or the PHP may be crashed by segfault and neither `try/catch` nor `register_shutdown_function` won't help.

Most common solution is error handling by the web server ([Nginx](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-to-use-custom-error-pages-on-ubuntu-14-04), [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html), etc). If upstream falls then web server gets 500 response and nicely handles it by showing user-friendly message.

Comment: Yep that a good point but if I set nginx error_page with fastcgi_intercept_errors, after that all my errors are handled by nginx (even errors I want to catch in Symfony).

Comment: You can create the custom ExceptionListener that set other HTTP code. If error is catchable and recoverable then it is not a 500. By design: "500 Internal server error: the server encountered an _unexpected_ condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request" (RFC2616).